# issue with @fastify/websocket and HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm writing a node app with fastify and @fastify/websocket. It's works fine on both local and remote servers until I use http protocol. As soon as I switch to https can't connect any anymore to ws/wss even though fastify keeps on working (https). This is my code:

node file:

```
const config = {
    privKey: process.env.PRIV_KEY,
    certKey: process.env.CERT_KEY,
    https: (process.env.HTTPS === '1' ? true : false),
    domains: process.env.DOMINI,
    port: process.env.PORT
}

const fastify = config.https === false
    ? require("fastify")({ serverTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000, logger: true })
    : require("fastify")({
        serverTimeout: 60 * 60 * 1000,
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(config.privKey),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(config.certKey),
        }
    });


fastify.register(require("@fastify/cors"), {
    origin: config.domains,
});

const WebSocket = require('@fastify/websocket'); 
fastify.register(WebSocket);


fastify.register(async function (fastify) {
    fastify.get('/live', { websocket: true }, (connection, request) => {

        connection.socket.on('message', message => {
            try {
                connection.socket.send('You are connected...')

            } catch(error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        })
    });
});

const start = () => {
    try {
        fastify.listen({
            host: '0.0.0.0',
            port: config.port,
            listenTextResolver: (address) => { return `Server is listening at ${address}` }
        });

    } catch (err) {
        fastify.log.error(err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

start();
```

Goggling I can't find any similar issue and cannot guess where the problem is. Even gpt 4 can't help. Firewall is open on tcp config.port and certificates are valid (fastify works fine on https).

It looks like websocket can't detect it'srunning on https istance of fastify.

Any help? Thank you

Simone

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the issue is related to SSL/TLS certificates. Using `mkcert` to generate certificates locally enables the `wss://` endpoint to work, suggesting this could be a viable approach for local and development environments.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've put the problem aside for now, but with your suggestion, I'll make further attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I dug a while and made this work by explicitly passing the fastify Node.js server instance as the `server` option to `@fastify/websocket`:

```js
const fastify = /* ... */

// ...

fastify.register(require('@fastify/websocket'), {
  // This line is key, as it passes the HTTPS-enabled
  // Node.js server to the underlying `ws` module:
  server: fastify.server
})
```

Not sure why fastify's websocket module doesn't do this on its own, but as long as your regular HTTPS endpoints work, this option should also make it work with WebSockets.

(Note that you'll still need to connect to the WebSocket via the `wss://` protocol in the browser.)

Comment: When I do this in TypeScript, it gives an error for passing `server` as a root option. To pass that option, I'd have to do `fastify.register(..., { options: { server: fastify.server } });`

Comment: I think reading the source code of `@fastify/websocket` is the most helpful (However, match the version you're using!) - https://github.com/fastify/fastify-websocket/blob/431cba461f0bdd133d607deee6cfc56b69ea379a/index.js

Comment: I had the same error in TypeScript, but the code is following the docs, so I have to assume that the package is poorly typed in this one instance.